# Concurrent usage of resources

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking, task-parallel-library

Please take a look at the following code. This is my attempt at understanding concurrent applications.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var consumers = new List<Consumer>
        {
            new Consumer(1000),
            new Consumer(900),
            new Consumer(800),
            new Consumer(700),
            new Consumer(600),
        };

        var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(consumers);
        resourceManager.Process();
    }
}

public class Resource
{
    private int Capacity { get; set; } = 1000;

    private Guid? _currentConsumer;

    public int GetCapacity(Guid? id)
    {
        while (id.HasValue && _currentConsumer.HasValue && id != _currentConsumer)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }

        _currentConsumer = id;
        return Capacity;
    }

    public void SetCapacity(int cap, Guid id)
    {
        if (_currentConsumer.HasValue && id != _currentConsumer)
            return;

        Capacity = cap;
        _currentConsumer = null;
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly int _sleep;

    private Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Consumer(int sleep)
    {
        _sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
    {
        var capture = resource.GetCapacity(_id);
        Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
        if (resource.GetCapacity(_id) != capture)
            throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
        resource.SetCapacity(resource.GetCapacity(_id) - 1, _id);
    }
}

public class ResourceManager
{
    private readonly List<Consumer> _consumers;
    public readonly Resource _resource;

    public ResourceManager(List<Consumer> consumers)
    {
        _consumers = consumers;
        _resource = new Resource();
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, _consumers.Count, i =>
        {
            var consumer = _consumers[i];
            consumer.ConsumeResource(_resource);
        });
    }
}
```

The lines of code from `Consumer::ConsumeResource`

```
Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
if (resource.GetCapacity(_id) != capture)
    throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
```

are meant to simulate a real application situation, when there are several consumers that might use the same resource, and which calculations can be broken if resource's state changes in process of calculations (probably by another consumer).

I created a solution for that, using good old `Thread.Sleep`, therefore locking resource from being used while it is already being used by another consumer, but I feel like there are more correct ways to achieve the same.

Looking forward for your review notes!

---

---

---

**EDITED:**

After some research about `lock`s and stuff, I wrote that little helper class:

```
public class ConcurrentAccessProvider<TObject>
{
    private readonly Func<TObject> _getter;
    private readonly Action<TObject> _setter;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public ConcurrentAccessProvider(Func<TObject> getter, Action<TObject> setter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
    }

    public TObject Get()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _getter();
        }
    }

    public void Set(TObject value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _setter(value);
        }
    }

    public void Access(Action accessAction)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            accessAction();
        }
    }
}
```

With that, I rewrote `Resource` and `Consumer` in order to make it thread-safe:

```
public class Resource
{
    public ConcurrentAccessProvider<int> CapacityAccessProvider { get; }
    private int _capacity;

    public Resource()
    {
        CapacityAccessProvider = new ConcurrentAccessProvider<int>(() => _capacity, val => _capacity = val);
    }

    public int Capacity
    {
        get => CapacityAccessProvider.Get();
        set => CapacityAccessProvider.Set(value);
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly int _sleep;

    public Consumer(int sleep)
    {
        _sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
    {
        resource.CapacityAccessProvider.Access(() =>
        {
            var capture = resource.Capacity;
            Thread.Sleep(_sleep);   // some calsulations and stuff
            if (resource.Capacity != capture)
                throw new SystemException("Something went wrong");
            resource.Capacity -= 1;

            Console.WriteLine(resource.Capacity);
        });
    }
}
```

In the provided example those manipulations effectively kill all possible profits from concurrency, but it is because there is only one `Resource` instance. In real world application when there are thousands of resources and only several conflicting cases, that will work just fine.

Nevertheless, I would still love to hear about how I could improve the concurrency related code!

Comment: Can you tell us please how this application works and why it needs the `Capacity` and what it is doing with that?

Comment: It could be benefitial to use something more concrete, like imagining a manufacturing process and name things accordingly (e.g. resource=steel) and actually produce something (e.g. nail) and check that you trully produced just enough given the resource. What cought my eye is `ConsumeResource` and possible race-conditions, lack of locking. See [lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) and [Interlocked](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked)

Comment: @t3chb0t Hey, thanks for answering! I know, the current example is a bit missleading with `capacity` and stuff like that. It is only to demonstrate that I somewhat rely on `Resource`s state. In real application it is something like a cell, which can contain only one object at a time, and while one thread is calculating what should be done with that cell, the other might be doing the same, and when one thread completes calculations and places new object in the cell, the other thread, which finishes calculations a few ticks later, cannot use already occupied cell. Hope this helps ;D

Comment: I suggest posting the original code + what you already have posted but just as an example for testing and running it e.g. in linqpad. This way we can better see the line between real-world use and demo/playaround app.

Comment: @firda Thanks for the remark! There is a concrete example, though it is to complicated to be posted here. Take a look at my answer to @t3chb0t. I believe you are right, I need to get rid from awaiting with `while` and `Thread.Sleep(5)`, and possibly use `lock`s for the same purpose, but I do not know how to do it exactly. I'll definetely take a look at your web links, thank you very much!

Comment: @t3chb0t I got it, I'll try to rework the actual code so it could be used outside the application as a more realistic example. Stay tuned :)

Comment: @t3chb0t, I edited my original post. I didn't rewrote the main logic of the example, but I sure improved the concurrency-related code. I hope to hear your opinions and thoughts on how to improve such code.

Comment: @firda, I edited my original post. I didn't rewrote the main logic of the example, but I sure improved the concurrency-related code. I hope to hear your opinions and thoughts on how to improve such code.

Comment: This sounds great but I think now your question needs some clean-up ;-) there are already two (?) versions of the resource-manager and I see two choices: either you need to pick one and remove the other one or leave them both there and tag your question with [tag:comparative-review].

Comment: @t3chb0t Alright, I removed the previous version. Now it's good to go, I hope ;D

Comment: Oh, at the time of writing it there were no answers yet and I'm afraid my suggestion does not apply anymore because the answer is now invalidated. I need to ask you to revert this edit... sorry ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t: I can refine/adjust the answer to current version, it is still pretty valid, all that appears to be needed is to mention there was a version of `ConsumeResource` not wrapped by the lock/Access and it should be ok, the points are still valid.

Comment: "pretty valid" isn't good enough. Invalidation occurred, so I'm forced to revert your edit. Answer invalidation is a point of concern that has to be taken seriously for this site to work.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first examine the content of `ConsumeResource` to understand why some form of [`locking`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) (now provided by `resource.CapacityAccessProvider.Access`) is needed. The `ConsumeResource` does this:

1. Get available resource total to local variable `capture = resource.Capacity`
2. Do some work (`Thread.Sleep`) assuming nobody changed available resources.
3. Check that nobody used any resource, that it still is same as our `capture`, throw if not.
4. Update available resource total, reducing it by the amount the work consumed.

The problem, if no [`locking`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) was used, would be that two or more consumers (threads) can simultaneously reach `resource.SetCapacity(resource.GetCapacity(_id) - 1, _id);` passing all checks. Let us imagine having 10 of the resource (e.g. steel) and 2 workers (producing nails), both (threads) could reach that line changing total resource to 10-1=9, but it should be 8! `SetCapacity(resource.GetCapacity(_id) - 1)` consists of three operations: get, substract and set. All the threads will `get` 10, `substract` 1 and reach the `set` having 9 *in hand*.

`resource.CapacityAccessProvider.Access` avoids this *race-condition*, by locking the whole process and you have correctly identified, that it does not run concurrently (*now, when the code got wrapped by the `Access`, which was not originally there*). The question is: **Does the very work need to acces shared state? Or just:**

1. Aquire resource (check that it is available and reduce total if it is)
2. Do some work with the acquired resource
3. Maybe output product and maybe loop (goto 1).

The difference is, that only the first part needs to be locked:

```
public void ConsumeResource(Resource resource)
{
    // acquire - only one thread can do this, other threads must wait
    lock(resource) // or resource.CapacityAccessProvider.Access(() =>
    {
        var capture = resource.GetCapacity(_id);
        if (capture < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough resource");
        resource.SetCapacity(capture - 1, _id);
    }
    // consume (work) - any number of threads can do this
    Thread.Sleep(_sleep);
    // maybe output:
    // lock(output) output.Add(nail);
}
```

Another alternative could be to use [atomic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) operation and the acquisition should probably become part of `Resource` (which is kinda resource manager and `ResourceManager` is rather process manager).